# SVG: Include more than one external .js-file

Tags: javascript, svg

I thought it`s as simple as HTML to include multiple external scripts in SVG.
But false ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="js/First_Script.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="js/Second_Script.js"/>
```

doing like this, none of the scripts will work.

It's not possible for me to include the content of the second script into the first, because the first will be automatically rewritten by a function in an external program.

any suggestion?

Cheers ... Peedy

Comment: displaying with Firefox ≥41.x

Comment: try <script></script> instead of <script/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<script></script>` instead of `<script/>`. this is a known issue with script tag and svg.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12989339)

Comment: Above is an answer based on my experience with similar issue. I am not asking for any clarification from the author.

Comment: Ok, I meant that you should have written more details in your answer...